# Função de concatenar duas listas encadeadas retornando somente um elemento

Tags: c++, lista-encadeada

Tenho uma função que recebe como parâmetro duas listas encadeadas contendo elementos e uma terceira lista vazia que ao final será a junção das duas, só que ao final da execução da função ela esta me retornando somente o ultimo elemento da lista de numero 2, no caso o primeiro elemento que foi inserido na segunda lista. Segue o código abaixo, a função que eu estou tendo problema é a função de nome Concatena_Listas.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct nolista  {
int dado;
nolista* prox;
};

nolista *Cria_Lista(){
return NULL;
}

nolista * Insere_Numero_Na_Lista(nolista *Ponteiro_De_Inserir, int Valor_A_Ser_Inserido){
if(Ponteiro_De_Inserir == NULL){
    Ponteiro_De_Inserir = (nolista *)malloc(sizeof(nolista));
    Ponteiro_De_Inserir -> dado = Valor_A_Ser_Inserido;
    Ponteiro_De_Inserir -> prox = NULL;
    return Ponteiro_De_Inserir;
}else{
    nolista *Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia;
    Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia = (nolista *) malloc(sizeof(nolista));
    Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia -> dado = Valor_A_Ser_Inserido;
    Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia -> prox = Ponteiro_De_Inserir;
    return Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia;
}
}

void Exibir_Lista(nolista *Ponteiro_De_Exibicao){
nolista *Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = Ponteiro_De_Exibicao;
printf("\n\nAbaixo estao os numeros da lista : \n"); 
while (Ponteiro_Para_Impressao != NULL)
{
    printf("\n%d", Ponteiro_Para_Impressao -> dado);
    Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = Ponteiro_Para_Impressao -> prox;
}
printf("\n");

}

nolista * Concatena_Listas(nolista *L1, nolista *L2, nolista *Lista_Concatenada){
nolista *Ponteiro_De_Insercao;
nolista *Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 = L1;
nolista *Ponteiro_Pecorre_L2 = L2;
while (Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 != NULL){
    if(Lista_Concatenada == NULL){
        Lista_Concatenada = (nolista *)malloc(sizeof(nolista));
        Lista_Concatenada -> dado = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 -> dado;
        Lista_Concatenada -> prox = NULL;
    }else{
        nolista *Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia;
        Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia = (nolista *) malloc(sizeof(nolista));
        Lista_Concatenada -> dado = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 -> dado;

      
        Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia -> prox = Lista_Concatenada;
       
        
        
    }
    Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 ->prox;
}
while (Ponteiro_Pecorre_L2 != NULL){
    if(Lista_Concatenada == NULL){
        Lista_Concatenada = (nolista *)malloc(sizeof(nolista));
        Lista_Concatenada -> dado = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L1 -> dado;
        Lista_Concatenada -> prox = NULL;
        
    }else{
        nolista *Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia;
        Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia = (nolista *) malloc(sizeof(nolista));
        Lista_Concatenada -> dado = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L2 -> dado;

        
        Ponteiro_Lista_Nao_Vazia -> prox = Lista_Concatenada; 
      
    }
    Ponteiro_Pecorre_L2 = Ponteiro_Pecorre_L2 ->prox;
    
}

return Lista_Concatenada; 

}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){ 
nolista * Lista_1, *Lista_2, *Lista_Concatenada;
Lista_1 = Cria_Lista();
Lista_2 = Cria_Lista();
Lista_Concatenada = Cria_Lista();
int Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_1,Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_2, 
Numero;
printf("\nDigite a quantidade de elementos da lista 1 : ");
scanf("%d", &Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_1);
for(int i = 0; i < Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_1; i++){
    printf("\nDigite o elemento da lista de numero [%d] : ", (i+ 1));
    scanf("%d", &Numero);
    Lista_1 = Insere_Numero_Na_Lista(Lista_1, Numero);
}

printf("\nDigite a quantidade de elementos da lista 2 : ");
scanf("%d", &Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_2);
for(int i = 0; i < Quantidade_De_Elementos_Da_Lista_L_2; i++){
    printf("\nDigite o elemento da lista de numero [%d] : ", (i+ 1));
    scanf("%d", &Numero);
    Lista_2 = Insere_Numero_Na_Lista(Lista_2, Numero);
}

Exibir_Lista(Lista_1);
Exibir_Lista(Lista_2);

Lista_Concatenada = Concatena_Listas(Lista_1, Lista_2, Lista_Concatenada);
Exibir_Lista(Lista_Concatenada);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Este é um programa em C? Apenas incluiu `iostream`... Sugiro reescrever `Concatena_Listas()`: para inserir na lista use o código que já escreveu. No loop interno testa toda hora se `Lista_Concatenada()`  é `NULL`. Não precisa do parâmetro 3. Note que uma lista não é um nó. Um nó não é uma lista, e não deveria ter referência aos dados nas funções da lista ou não vai ser útil depois

Comment: E porque precisa de ponteiros para as duas listas originais se só acessa uma por vez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu escrevi no comentário na questão, acho que seu programa não está bom do modo como escreveu, e sugiro reescrever considerando que uma lista não é um nó, um nó não é uma lista, E não deveria ter referência aos dados na estrutura da lista, ou não vai conseguir usar para outros casos. Do modo como escreveu para qualquer mudança nos dados terá que mexer na lista toda.

Em relação à concatenar duas listas, usando seu código e considerando só essa função:

```
nolista* Concatena_Listas(nolista* L1, nolista* L2)
{
    nolista* p = L2;
    nolista* nova = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    {   nova = Insere_Numero_Na_Lista(nova, p->dado);
        p = p->prox;
    }
    p = L1;
    while (p != NULL)
    {   nova = Insere_Numero_Na_Lista(nova, p->dado);
        p = p->prox;
    }
    return nova;
}
```

acho que já funciona. É melhor usar seu próprio código para inserir do que reescrever...